# Why curl is working locally but failing when in my web hosting?

Tags: php, json, curl, web-hosting

I have this code:

```
    $jsonurl = "http://ipinfo.io";
    $ch = curl_init($jsonurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $predata = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);       
    $data = json_decode($predata, true);
```

It is working great locally but when I upload it into my web hosting I have:

```
string(20) "connect() timed out!"
```

phpinfo in my web hosting says:

```
URL support enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
```

Can you, please give any clues on how to search where the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: Increase the connection timeout? Maybe it's just very slow.

Answer (score 0):

don't sure but , maybe your ip will be block from remote server !

or you need more time out , try adding this

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
```

to your code

**NOTE**:CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT set to zero for no timeout

> CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
>
> The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
>
> CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT
>
> The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

hope these help

Comment: thanks but I added the 400  and it is not working :(